# Facebook SDK v4 for PHP Minimal Example

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to get the minimal example

```
using Facebook\FacebookSession;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('YOUR_APP_ID','YOUR_APP_SECRET');

// Use one of the helper classes to get a FacebookSession object.
//   FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
//   FacebookCanvasLoginHelper
//   FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper
// or create a FacebookSession with a valid access token:
$session = new FacebookSession('access-token-here');

// Get the GraphUser object for the current user:

try {
  $me = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'GET', '/me'
  ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
  echo $me->getName();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
  // The Graph API returned an error
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  // Some other error occurred
}
```

from the [README](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/master/README.md) working, but I don't understand what the first line of code means. Where do I have to put the PHP file using that minimal code example within the SDK file structure. I tried directly in the src folder, but that returns the following PHP error

```
[01-May-2014 20:12:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Facebook' (T_STRING) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/test.php on line 9
```

The file structure looks like this

```
├── src
│   ├── Facebook
│   │   ├── FacebookAuthorizationException.php
│   │   ├── FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php
│   │   ├── FacebookClientException.php
│   │   ├── FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper.php
│   │   ├── FacebookOtherException.php
│   │   ├── FacebookPermissionException.php
│   │   ├── FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php
│   │   ├── FacebookRequest.php
│   │   ├── FacebookRequestException.php
│   │   ├── FacebookResponse.php
│   │   ├── FacebookSDKException.php
│   │   ├── FacebookServerException.php
│   │   ├── FacebookSession.php
│   │   ├── FacebookThrottleException.php
│   │   ├── GraphLocation.php
│   │   ├── GraphObject.php
│   │   ├── GraphSessionInfo.php
│   │   ├── GraphUser.php
│   │   └── fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt
│   └── test.php
```

Comment: The Facebook PHP SDK is the most shameful piece of code I ever saw in my life - and this is after 10 years of nutting my head with Micrsosoft...

Comment: @PalDev Yes you are right. Those programmers in Facebook are really genius!

Answer (score 22):

have recently solved this.
as there is autoload.php file available with sdk you dont need to use require etc etc.
just include that autoload.php on the start

```
 <?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

// start session

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'app-id','app-secret' );

// login helper with redirect_uri

    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://yourhost/facebook/' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  // print data
  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}

?>
```

after this you must have to check the path in autoload.php file

```
$base_dir = defined('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR') ? FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR : __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/';
```

this line is default code if u have changed the name of directories like placed all the files from /src/Facebook/ to /sdk/ then just replace the name
always check the included path by using `die(__DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/');`
to make sure if it is correct.

Comment: +1 I couldn't get the autoloader to work but after changing the path in autoload.php I got it to work

Comment: you might want to remove your app secret from the answer

Answer (score 10):

There is a complete (working) example here: http://metah.ch/blog/2014/05/facebook-sdk-4-0-0-for-php-a-working-sample-to-get-started/

Code:

```
session_start();
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APPID','SECRET');

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.metah.ch/' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  // print data
  echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to change this line:

```
using Facebook\FacebookSession;
```

to

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
```

to use a namespace in php the keyword is `use` more on [php using namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

**Update:**

using namespaces does not automatically include the script, you either need to include the path in your autoload (if you have one) or simply:

```
include 'path/to/FacebookSession.php';
```

**Update2:** first, please read the php namespaces in the manual, second, no, if it is already included in the original class then you don't. or if it is adhering to psr-* then you can use some autoloader or use [spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: Thanks, that removed the parse error and created a new one

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/test.php on line 11

Comment: @NickWeisser - what is the new one?

Comment: you need to include it too

Comment: Will add my SDK file structure in the initial question.

Comment: So it looks like I have to include whichever class is required?

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable help so far. I still didn't get the minimal example from Github working. I wish there was a complete tutorial somewhere for the v4 SDK.

Comment: The SDK now [includes an autoloader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532858/facebook-graph-api-php-sdk-v4-post-on-page/23942425#23942425).

Answer (score 3):

To avoid using `require` or `require_once` and to have a better project structure you should follow the following steps:

1. Install composer from https://getcomposer.org/
2. Create `composer.json` file in your web application root with the following contents:

   `{
     "require" : {
       "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"
     }
   }`
3. Call `php composer.phar install`
4. Create a folder `src/Acme/App`
5. Create a file `src/Acme/App/Run.php` with the following contents:

`<?php`

```
namespace Acme\App;

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

class Run {
    const APP_ID = 'app_id';
    const APP_SECRET = 'app_secret';

    public function __construct()
    {
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(self::APP_ID, self::APP_SECRET);
       // ...your code goes here...
    }

}
```

1. Create an `index.php` file with the following contents:

`<?php`

```
$loader = require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Acme\App', __DIR__.'/src');
$app = new Run();
```

This will be a skeleton of your Facebook application (all your further classes should follow PSR-4 standard). Using composer's autoloader you will not need to use `require_once` for classes in any registered namespace.

P.S. You may want to remove all your libraries from the web root. It will help to prevent direct access from web to them. Then you can just adjust the pathnames and keep only index.php in your web root. I hope, it's clear.

Comment: i should think this would be well documented on the FB website, but i was unable to find it.  thank you very much for taking the time to explain this.  your example worked perfectly using facebook login.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the new tutorials aren't very helpful.

I'm running through them, myself, and just to get the examples to work, I did:

```
function facebookLoader($class) {
    require "/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4-master/src/" . str_replace("\\", "/", $class) . ".php";
}

spl_autoload_register("facebookLoader");

Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication([...]
```

and prepended `Facebook\` anywhere where was a class name being called.

Also, there's a part in the tutorial where it says to use: 
`FacebookRedirectLoginHelper();`

When you, in fact, still have to give the thing input:

`FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("http://yourRedirectUri.com/");`

Got me through the tutorial - ! Now on to figuring out how to get the user's email/complete profile information.

Answer (score 1):

1. PHP Version 5.4.0 or higher is required.
2. Facebook uses [Implementations of PSR-4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md). Hence You dont have to use **require or require_once or include or include_once**.
3. In PSR-4, you just need packagename(namespace) i.e. directory name and class file name only.It will register classes dynamically from given package name.Ex.:- `use packaname\classname`.
4. You will find the file **autoload.php** in [Facebook SDK Autoload](https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacebook%2Ffacebook-php-sdk-v4%2Farchive%2F4.0-dev.zip&h=GAQGYSrzE&s=1) root directory.
5. `use` is used to load dynamic classes using `spl_autoload_register`
6. Facebook register all library using `autoload.php` or `autoload_fb.php`
7. You have to find autoload.php in your downloaded library like `facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/`.
8. If you just wants to use **Facebook** library from download source.Then you have to copy **autoload.php** in your root directory or in Facebook directory.
9. defined constant for `FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR` i.e. path of the facebook library
10. You need to do as below to **use** in php

**Note:** I have copied `/var/www/stack/24006673/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook` directory and `/var/www/stack/24006673/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php` file in root directory `/var/www/stack/24006673/`

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR','/var/www/stack/24006673/Facebook/');
require_once("autoload.php");
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('YOUR_APP_ID','YOUR_APP_SECRET');
```

Comment: You can also edit the directory value in autoload.php on line 49, instead of defining the constant before including the file. For instance, I changed /src/Facebook/ to /Facebook/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Just use following line at the top of your script:

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
```

and you are done.

Answer (score -1):

just put this on include page:

require **DIR** . '/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';

Also call the class before use, each time you need:

use Facebook\FacebookSession;