# Facebook Graph API PHP SDK v4 - Post on Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanna give all my website authors a possiblity to post their articles on our facebook page without having go give them admin access to it.

So i created a simple form, where the author types in: URL, URL to image, message

On submit, this form will send a ajax request to facebook.php where the magic "should" happen.

The first problem occurs at "require_once".
It's not possible to require all 4 files without having an error.
If i get rid of the facebook exception, then everything works except the request itself. 
There seems to be an PHP Error, because i get no ajax response at all.

```
session_start();

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sys/facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sys/facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sys/facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sys/facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

$message = safe($_POST["message"]);
$url = safe($_POST["url"]);
$image = safe($_POST["image"]);

if($message == "" OR $url == "" OR $image == ""){
    echo "incomplete";
    return;
}

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('{APP ID}','{APP SECRET}');
$session = new FacebookSession('{Page Access Token}');

if($session) {
    try {
        $response = (new FacebookRequest(
            $session, 'POST', '/{Page ID}/feed', array(
                'message'       => $message,
                'link'          => $url,
                'picture'       => $image
            )
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
        echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
        echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
        echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo "No Session available!";
}
```

Comment: yes cUrl is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** *June, 27 2014*, The SDK now comes with a [built-in autoloader](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/pull/135) for those who can't use composer.

```
require __DIR__ . '/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';
```

If that doesn't automatically find the path for you, you can define it with `FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR`.

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';
```

---

The internals of the SDK rely on several other classes that you're not including. That's why autoloading is really important here.

## Autoloading With Composer

The best way to do this is to [install composer](https://getcomposer.org/). And add the SDK in a `composer.json` file to the root of your project.

```
{
    "require" : {
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"
    }
}
```

Then run `composer install` from the command line where the `composer.json` file is. Then include the autoloader at the top of your script.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

## Manual Autoloading

An alternative way to autoload these files is to replace your `require_once`'s at the top with this solution from [rm-vanda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23548510/443479):

```
function facebookLoader($class) {
    require "/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4-master/src/" . str_replace("\\", "/", $class) . ".php";
}

spl_autoload_register("facebookLoader");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I got my solution fixing on updating the Facebook Graph SDK, I do apologize for the short answer.

I updated, php.ini file and enabled, the fileinfo extension by uncommenting

```
;extension=fileinfo
```

Removing the ; tag to

```
extension=fileinfo
```

Then do the command,

```
composer update
```

Credits: StackOverflow, Bing, and Google search.
Warning: I'm using, Laravel, Wnmp as a local webserver.
Note: This comment may require revisions.