# Class 'FacebookSession' not found - API Facebook 4.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

i'm trying the new Facebook API (4.0) and I have serious problem with this.

The code of my page loginUser.php is:

```
<?php
require_once("autoload_fb.php");


// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '647345538685342','6ea4dc94874b31a637b6fe368bcfba76' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.radiobrunoestate.mumbleserver.it/api/loginUser' );

// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }

} else {
  // no session exists

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo $ex->message;
  }

}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

  // print profile data
  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';

  // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://yourwebsite.com/app/logout.php' ) . '">Logout</a>';

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '">Login</a>';
  }
?>
```

and the **autoload_fb.php** is simply:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
?>
```

I get this error on first server:

```
Fatal error: Class 'FacebookSession' not found in /home/jack/provaprova/api/loginUser.php on line 6
```

Testing the same code on another Server i have this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/eyikmdnu/public_html/jack/provaprova/api/Facebook/FacebookSession.php on line 140
```

Where could be the problem? could be a problem of the server configuration?

Thanks

Comment: How did you solved this problem? i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Facebook PHP SDK v4 requires PHP 5.4. You are most likely using an older version of PHP.

Comment: On the first server, the one that has the error:

Fatal error: Class 'FacebookSession' not found

I have PHP 5.4.26

Comment: (On the second server I have PHP 5.3 well it's explained the error... But I don't know why id does not work on first)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put the **"use"** statements also in the top of the **"loginUser.php"** file.

Suppose you've already made it work, but I think that was the problem.

Maybe this can help someone else.

Comment: That was my function. I didn't know you couldn't use 'use' inside an object method.

Comment: No you cannot. You have to use it outside your class and functions. On the top of the file for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your `use` statements from the include file won't import them for the main file. So you'll need to move the `use` statements to your main file right after your include of the `autoload_fb.php` file.

But then you'll have another issue. Your autoloader isn't a real autoloader. [Here's more info on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532858/facebook-graph-api-php-sdk-v4-post-on-page/23942425#23942425).