# Error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found with the facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am having a hard time with facebook's SDK documentation. I downloaded the SDK from Github and added it into my PHP project.

Here is the file system:

```
   ├── Facebook
   │   ├── FacebookAuthorizationException.php
   │   ├── FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php
   │   ├── FacebookClientException.php
   │   ├── FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper.php
   │   ├── FacebookOtherException.php
   │   ├── FacebookPermissionException.php
   │   ├── FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php
   │   ├── FacebookRequest.php
   │   ├── FacebookRequestException.php
   │   ├── FacebookResponse.php
   │   ├── FacebookSDKException.php
   │   ├── FacebookServerException.php
   │   ├── FacebookSession.php
   │   ├── FacebookThrottleException.php
   │   ├── GraphLocation.php
   │   ├── GraphObject.php
   │   ├── GraphSessionInfo.php
   │   ├── GraphUser.php
   │   └── fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt
   └── test.php
```

here is my code so far:

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('*******','******');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://isgeek.eu/fb/FaRepost/return.php');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
// Use the login url on a link or button to redirect to Facebook for authentication
```

I get this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found in /homepages/2/d184071366/htdocs/isgeek/fb/FaRepost/test.php on line 9
```

At updated my PHP version, so the issue does not comme from here. It seems like the PHP files are not found. I read this question ([Facebook SDK v4 for PHP Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413854/facebook-sdk-v4-for-php-minimal-example)) but it does not help.

Where does this comme from?

Comment: what is there in facebooksession file,is there any class defined with this name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook SDK v4 for PHP Minimal Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413854/facebook-sdk-v4-for-php-minimal-example)

Comment: The FacebookSession class is no longer available in v5.x of the SDK (which is still under the php-sdk-v4 name). A blog post that will help you move from 4.x to 5.x of the SDK can be found here. https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v4-to-v5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://metah.ch/blog/2014/05/facebook-sdk-4-0-0-for-php-a-working-sample-to-get-started/#post-937)

I did not code in php for some time now and things have changed. `use Facebook\FacebookSession;` is not enough. You need to add a `require_once` too.

```
require_once 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php';
```

Comment: Yeah it's kind of weird that in none of the Facebook documentation they mention which files to include!

Comment: You have to include **autoload.php** from your downloaded library like facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/. Answer is provided as below

Comment: @rajeshujade can you please post your sample code here, i did that and its not working ,i tried almost all the ways, it still says same error class not found

Comment: @IftikarUrrhmanKhan I have added the answer to this question. Also you can check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413854/facebook-sdk-v4-for-php-minimal-example/25737047#25737047

Answer (score 20):

1. PHP Version 5.4.0 or higher is required.
2. Facebook uses [Implementations of PSR-4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md). Hence You dont have to use **require or require_once or include or include_once**.
3. In PSR-4, you just need packagename(namespace) i.e. directory name and class file name only.It will register classes dynamically from given package name.Ex.:- `use packaname\classname`.
4. You will find the file **autoload.php** in [Facebook SDK Autoload](https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacebook%2Ffacebook-php-sdk-v4%2Farchive%2F4.0-dev.zip&h=GAQGYSrzE&s=1) root directory.
5. `use` is used to load dynamic classes using `spl_autoload_register`
6. Facebook register all library using `autoload.php` or `autoload_fb.php`
7. You have to find autoload.php in your downloaded library like `facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/`.
8. If you just wants to use **Facebook** library from download source.Then you have to copy **autoload.php** in your root directory or in Facebook directory.
9. defined constant for `FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR` i.e. path of the facebook library
10. You need to do as below to **use** in php

**Note:** I have copied `/var/www/stack/24006673/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook` directory and `/var/www/stack/24006673/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php` file in root directory `/var/www/stack/24006673/`

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR','/var/www/stack/24006673/Facebook/');
require_once("autoload.php");
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('YOUR_APP_ID','YOUR_APP_SECRET');
```

Comment: Can you explain more about PSR-4? I can't tell if it's something I need to install or a programming technique.

Comment: I just added the line `require_once("autoload.php");` and it worked thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should be careful with all the paths!

I cannot see "autoload.php" in your file system. In my case I put the content of PHP SDK in the directory "fb", and use the paths (added **DIR** . into the "define" line in comparison with the example of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0)

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/fb/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/fb/autoload.php';

echo FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR; //to check if the paths are correct

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
<...>
```

It helped to avoid that kind of the error.

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me

```
session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' ); 

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl; 

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('XXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX');

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://localhost/demo/demo2/demo2.php' );

try {

  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  // print data
  echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
```

Comment: Do not use `require_once()`. That's not Facebook suggests. Use namespace autoload approach instead.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `require` or `include`.
I solved it. Just use following line at the top of your script:

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app_id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app_secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);
```

-just add this code .it works.
  enter your app_id and app_secret of your facebookAPP

Answer (score -1):

Rename all Facebook files and directories to lower case. Auto-loading on *nix automatically lowercases all files names.

Comment: No, just no. How can you update the next version then?

Comment: You can always repeat the process after updating. I admit this was a quick fix I did without investigating if there is a better solution, but this solution worked perfectly.