# Facebook Graph API V2.4 not returning all post data of Facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am trying to get page post data using facebook PHP SDK v4.0.5.
My app is also approved for manage_pages permission.
Now problem is with the response i am getting from api function:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
      'app_id' => $appID,
      'app_secret' => $appSecret,
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
      ));

    $responce = $fb->get("/thealonekhaan/feed", $access_token);                 
    echo '<pre>';print_r($responce);exit;
```

This api call is returning following data:

```
   [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [message] => new post
                        [created_time] => 2015-09-21T07:23:33+0000
                        [id] => 106750526111915_841900919263535
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [story] => Alone KHAN shared a link.
                        [created_time] => 2015-08-28T06:42:01+0000
                        [id] => 106750526111915_828769187243375
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [message] => hat trick B|
                        [story] => Alone KHAN shared Hamza Ali Abbasi's video.
                        [created_time] => 2015-08-28T06:02:49+0000
                        [id] => 106750526111915_828762167244077
                    )
```

.....

It is showing only 3 or 4 page post item and i need all the data of post like picture, post link, post image, category, comments, likes etc. 
How can i get these page post items.

Comment: I am using a long-lived-access-token, reference to this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124078/get-latest-facebook-posts-of-page-with-php-sdk)

Comment: The fact that this is not returning all the fields is expected. This was announced here: https://developers.intern.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/07/08/graph-api-v2.4/. Also see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields as an example of how to get additional information on your request.

Comment: Thanks @corvuszero, it was helpfull.