# Facebook login not working PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, api

This is my code (App id and App secret are ok):

```
session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('App_id', 'App_secret');
```

The error I get is :

> Fatal error: Interface 'Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable' not
>   found in
>   /home/superwed/public_html/HS/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php
>   on line 33

Which is very wierd because everywhere I checked everything is defined ok.

Comment: You are facing this problem because your are not using namespaces. For this you need autoload.php. It will register all the required classes dnyamically. For detail check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413854/facebook-sdk-v4-for-php-minimal-example/25737047#25737047

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to require `Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php` before `Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php` because the latter *depends on* the former.

Edit: so this Q/A can be helpful to others, you will likely save many a headache by forgoing the require statements and using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) which has its own [autoloader function](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and is recommended in [Facebook's PHP SDK guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0). Alternatively, you could write your own autoloader.

Comment: You don't have to use require method. For detail check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413854/facebook-sdk-v4-for-php-minimal-example/25737047#25737047