# php Facebook SDK namespace error

Tags: php, facebook, namespaces, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get the new facebook php sdk setup on my site. I'm running the latest stable version of php. I have never messed with namespaces before. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I get this error

**Fatal error: Class 'FacebookSession' not found in**

When I run this code

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxx','yyy' );
```

.....

```
// path of these files have changes
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

// other files remain the same
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( '/var/www/vhosts/server/site/lib/fb/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

// path of these files have changes
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
```

Comment: You probably need composer to handle autoload and dependency for the SDK.

Comment: I'm reading about composer now. Why would it make a difference as compared to having the files on my site? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Would my autoloader for my other classes break it? 
function __autoload($class_name) {
 
 if(file_exists(ROOT.LIBRARY . $class_name . '/class.' .$class_name . '.php')) {
  
     require_once ROOT.LIBRARY . $class_name . '/class.' .$class_name . '.php';
  
 }
}

Comment: Maybe no go ahead and try.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the php folder to install it to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook SDK v4 for PHP Minimal Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413854/facebook-sdk-v4-for-php-minimal-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to PEAR being installed on the server for email. The include path in php settings was modified.

I actually removed PEAR, set PHP back to it's default include path and switched email to swiftmailer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the full path to the Facebook SDK unless you are trying to access it from a totally different location. You should be able to access it using a relative path, like `lib/fb/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php`, assuming your index.php file is located in the `site` folder.

Also, try doing the following and see if you still get an error:

```
Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxx','yyy' );
```