# Yet another PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Tags: php, facebook

I lost my evening on this and I feel like I need somebody other to check this, I'm probably completely blind.

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/var/www/rateanything/facebook-sdk/src/Facebook');
require('/var/www/rateanything/facebook-sdk/autoload.php');
use Facebook;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('my_app_id', 'my_app_secret');
$session = new FacebookSession($fbtoken);
$request = new FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/me?fields=email,name,gender');
```

Why this is not duplicate: Because that question has not this error. I'm getting this parse error.

I'm using PHP 5.4.

Comment: check there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413854/facebook-sdk-v4-for-php-minimal-example

Comment: no, that didn't help me. Why that downvote? :|

Answer (score 13):

Is that code wrapped inside a function? The use keyword can only be applied on the outermost scope of your file.

Basically, move `use Facebook;` to the top of the file.

Alternatively, you could probably reference the namespace in which `FacebookSession` and `FacebookRequest` is defined. Like so:

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/var/www/rateanything/facebook-sdk/src/Facebook');
require('/var/www/rateanything/facebook-sdk/autoload.php');
Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('my_app_id', 'my_app_secret');
$session = new Facebook\FacebookSession($fbtoken);
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/me?fields=email,name,gender');
```

Comment: It's not in a function, but it's in "if", where I check if the person is logging in via G+ or Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

So based on the error this is the problem line

```
use Facebook;
```

Without knowing what's in that include it's hard to say, but it doesn't look like you're aliasing anything. In fact, if you're autoloading (which seems like a safe bet) you shouldn't use an alias like that.

Normally you'd use it like this

```
include 'facebook.php';
use Facebook;
\Facebook\SomeClass::staticFunction($var);
$class = new \Facebook\OtherClass();
```

Check out [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) for more details and examples on how to use `use`

Comment: in Facebook's readme on this project https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4 is code like my... I copied it from there.

Comment: Are you using Composer?

Comment: No, I'm not using Composer